# How do I pull out the tags/categories from the feature files?

Tags: c#, selenium, cucumber, bdd, specflow

We are looking to create documentation around our Feature files. We can pull the existing step definitions from the feature files using the built in SpecFlow stepdefinitionreport feature.

What we also want is the tags/categories that help group and run our tests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Pickles](http://www.picklesdoc.com/) to create documentation for Specflow. You should be able to get all tags and categories.

Comment: This looks pretty good. But is there a way to just pull the tags/categories into a file versus everything? We can already get our steps in a nicely sorted html view from specflow. What we don't get is the tags.

Comment: Was there a resolution to this? I'm looking for a way of extracting all the tags and their scenarios from the feature files in a BDD project. I dont need all the other living documentation.